# Lucene index field value is stripped of all html tags

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I have a Lucene index in which one of the fields is mapped to Sitecore's rich text field.

Since this field value contains html content for most of the items sharing the template, I expected html content to be returned when fetching the item's field value. However, I noticed that the value returned is stripped of all html tags.

I tried changing the INDEXTYPE to "UNTOKENTIZED". Yet this did not solve the problem. I understand that Lucene does this to allow searching based on that field. But that is not a requirement in my case and I want this behavior overridden.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using?

Answer (score 5):

It happens because there is a `RichTextFieldReader` assigned to the `html` and `rich text` fields:

```xml
<fieldReader 
    fieldTypeName="html|rich text"                                     
    fieldNameFormat="{0}"
    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.RichTextFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
```

In Sitecore 8.1 it's defined in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`.

It strips out all the tags using `HtmlField.GetPlainText()`.

You can try to add another section at the same level as `<mapFieldByTypeName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldTypeName">` section and use something like:

```xml
<mapFieldByFieldName hint="AddFieldReaderByFieldName">
    <fieldReader 
        fieldName="yourFieldName"
        fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
```

Mapping by `fieldName` has higher priority than mapping by field type, so it will use `fieldRendered` specified for your field instead of using the one specified for the type of your field.

Comment: Just tried this...but it gives me object reference error after opening Indexing Manager. I also changed the fieldreadertype to one below without success:

<fieldReader fieldTypeName="html|rich text"  fieldNameFormat="{0}" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any typo and you copied exactly what I pasted? `hint="AddFieldReaderByFieldName"` and `fieldReader 
        fieldName="..."`? What is the stack trace of object reference?

Comment: I'm working on Sitecore 7.5 this solution did not work for me, any suggestions, i have custom lucene index configs, some index have html but others don't

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a computed index field and this should save the HTML correctly in the index.

```
public class TileHtml : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        Item indexedContent = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (indexedContent != null && indexedContent.Fields[ITileConstants.TileHtmlFieldName] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(indexedContent.Fields[ITileConstants.TileHtmlFieldName].Value))
        {
            return indexedContent.Fields[ITileConstants.TileHtmlFieldName].Value;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```

You can then register the filed in your Lucene Index

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
<field fieldName="TileHtml" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED">Namespace.TileHtml, Assembly</field>
```